# Microsoft Web Matrix

Tags: webmatrix

Pretty easy question I hope: does anyone know of a tool that will effectively scrape sites built with Microsoft Matrix? I could write the code in python, but it will take me way longer than I think I want to dedicate to the task, namely because of the really bad and ugly HTML generated by Matrix.

I have tried Web Harvey, Helium Scraper, and I tried the Web Scraper plugin for Chrome. WebHarvey choked on the HTML and couldn't load subsequent pages. Helium Scraper was able to move from one details page to another (the Next links were followed) but content from within the details pages was not lifted out. The Chrome plugin web scraper was not able to navigate links, with the popup window displaying an error page. My gut is telling me that this has to do with uniquely ASP.net things, but I could be wrong.

Any pointers or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Yours is a good question.  Please consider adding more details about the errors you're encountering.  SUGGESTION: Google "screen scape tools for asp.net pages".  Please let us know what you find!

Answer (score 1):

You know there are two completely different versions of Microsoft Web Matrix right?   There's the one from 2003; i have no idea what its html looks like.  There's the one from 2011 to current which uses razor cshtml source files to produce its html.  In the 2011+ one, you write the html by hand; there's no drag and drop, and so it's unlikely you'll get consistent html from site to site.

Comment: This I did not know. The HTML is pretty terrible and inconsistent. Here's a fun sample:

<TD class="d1289m28"><span class="label d1289m32">Title Company:</SPAN></TD>
<TD class="d1289m33" colSpan=3><SPAN class="field">Land Title Guarantee</span></TD></TR>
<TR class="d1289m34">
<TD class="d1289m28"><span class="label">Financial Terms:</SPAN></TD>
<TD class="d1289m33" colSpan=3><SPAN class="field wrapped-field">Cash,Conventional</span>, <span class="field"></span></TD></TR>

What's giving me trouble is seemingly random-formed HTML meaning it's impossible to extract data.

Comment: The current version of webMatrix doesn't generate classes so perhaps that was all from the older version.  It looks reminiscent of using Word to generate html.